# How to get data out of a fetch request

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, fetch, es6-promise

I've been trying to move from XHR to fetch. When I make a GET request, I can't figure out how to get data out of the response, all I get is more promise objects that still don't contain any data. I just want the data as a string.

UPDATE: my code so far isn't much to speak of:

```
fetch(URL)
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  return response;
});
```

...where URL is the URL of an API that returns some data as JSON

Comment: Can you please post your code ?

Comment: Are you chaining the fetch call with `then`? For example `fetch('foo.xhr').then(handleFoo)`.

Comment: @KalpeshRajai I've updated the question.

Comment: if using the [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) module, make sure to call `.json()` on the response.

Comment: I would edit my previous comment, but it has been past 5 minutes: If you are using the built-in javascript [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) you also need to call `.json()` on the response and call `.then()` as it returns a promise as well.

Comment: @httpNick I've done that and the response object within .json().then() still doesn't have any useable data